# php - how can i getting a web page content with curl for this site

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

how can i getting a web page content with curl for this site:
divar . ir

I want try to get a page from a website with curl,But not work

I wrote the following code page 404 is displayed.

```
function get_web_page( $url )
{
    $options = array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,     // return web page
        CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,    // don't return headers
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,     // follow redirects
        CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",       // handle all encodings
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => "spider", // who am i
        CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,     // set referer on redirect
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,      // timeout on connect
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,      // timeout on response
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,       // stop after 10 redirects

        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false     // Disabled SSL Cert checks


    );



    $ch      = curl_init( $url );
    curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );
    $content = curl_exec( $ch );
    $err     = curl_errno( $ch );
    $errmsg  = curl_error( $ch );
    $header  = curl_getinfo( $ch );
    curl_close( $ch );

    $header['errno']   = $err;
    $header['errmsg']  = $errmsg;
    $header['content'] = $content;
    return $header;
}



$link="https://divar.ir/";
$res =get_web_page($link);
echo $res['content'];
```

Comment: Your code works perfectly here. Perhaps you've been blocked for scraping the site.

Comment: no this not work, i tested in localhost and Several ip: 

http://www.babynames.ir/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/unnamed.jpg

 @ceejayoz

Comment: did you open this site with a browser?

Comment: yes divar.ir Correctly displayed but, is displayed with curl page 404 @Deadooshka

Comment: feed it all browser request headers

Comment: Please tell me how to change my code to work correctly @Deadooshka

Comment: see 1st comment. `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => ['Host: divar.ir', 'Connection: keep-alive', 'Pragma: no-cache', 'Cache-Control: no-cache' /* etc. */ ]`

Comment: `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => ['Host: divar.ir', 'Connection: keep-alive', 'Pragma: no-cache', 'Cache-Control: no-cache' /* etc. */ ], `

It also does not work @Deadooshka

Answer (score 0):

Change CURLOPT_USERAGENT

CURLOPT_USERAGENT => "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:53.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/53.0",

Comment: It also does not work

`
 CURLOPT_USERAGENT      =>  "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:53.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/53.0"
      
`

Comment: "https://divar.ir/"  - secure

Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
If-None-Match: W/"fdf5-PbFQJsgYicO3dRkRzC8NHA"

your need have  key  W/"fdf5-PbFQJsgYicO3dRkRzC8NHA"  for  getting your CURL

Comment: Please tell me how to change my code to work correctly @user3126867